# How to get all registered routers in ember (version 2.4.6) by es6

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I need a list of all registered routers in ember app.
After searching on the Internet, I've found the link below:

[can we view all the routes in emberjs aka something similar to what rake routes does in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756458/can-we-view-all-the-routes-in-emberjs-aka-something-similar-to-what-rake-routes)

[Getting a list of routes in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274005/getting-a-list-of-routes-in-ember-js)

But it does not work for me.

this is App.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Resolver from './resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember-load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';
let App;
Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;
App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
    Resolver,
    ready: function () {  
    }
});
loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);    
export default App;
```

this is router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {    
    this.route('about');
    this.route('login');
});

export default Router;
```

---

and this is Application Conroller for get all routers

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import App from 'ember-app/app';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    allRouter: [],

    allRouterCalc: Ember.computed('allRouter', function() {        
        let allRouter = this.get('allRouter');
        if(allRouter.length === 0)
        {
            allRouter = App.Router.router.recognizer.names;
        }        
        return allRouter;
    })
});
```

---

but when I called "allRouterCalc" variable, this error This bug occurs:
"Cannot read property 'router' of undefined" .

This problem arises because the "Router" in "App.Router" is "undefined".

why "Router"  is "undefined" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one `Router` for every ember apps. So I think you mean you want list all routes.

You can list all routes like this :

```
let router = Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('router:main');
let allRoutesList = router.get('router.recognizer.names');
```

**Note**: This works with version 2.x

Comment: Thank you, Your answers helped me.
But is there a reliable source that can find out to answer of  these questions  about ember?

Comment: No longer works in ember v3.*, however you may be able to find a hack with the new router service.

Comment: @MattJensen Yeah, I don't try with v3.x

Comment: This has been deprecated: Use `router._routerMicrolib.recognizer.names` instead.